# Missing IP_MTU socket option define on Debian Etch?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, debian

I'm trying to read the **MTU** of my **TCP connection** using `IP_MTU` socket option 
According to `man 7 ip` installed on my **Debian Etch** (I know, it's quite old, but changing it is not an option right now):

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/socket.h>
       #include <netinet/in.h>
       #include <netinet/ip.h> /* superset of previous */
[CUT]
IP_MTU Retrieve the current known path MTU of the current socket.
Only valid when the socket has been  connected.  Returns  an integer.  
Only valid as a getsockopt(2).
```

Problem is that the above socket option is not present in any of the include files named by the man page. (hence my code is not compiling ;)) 
I instead found it defined in `<linux/in.h>` (`grep` is your friend)
If I try adding `<linux/in.h>` to my source code I get all kind of multiple definition/re-declaration compile errors. 
Does anyone out there knows why the above param is missing from the headers and how to solve the issue? 
Many thanks
Sergio

Comment: Is the definition present only in `linux/in.h`? Isn't it present in `xxxxx/bits/in.h`? `netinet/in.h` seems to be including `in.h` under `bits` folder (at least on my system). You could try to see only the preprocessor output (using `gcc`'s `-E` option) & grep for "include" to see the files included & check if any of them have the definition.

Comment: It seems the only file defining it is `linux/in.h`  `vm-etch-dev32# grep -rn IP_MTU *
bits/in.h:61:#define IP_MTU_DISCOVER    10 /* int; see below */
bits/in.h:67:/* IP_MTU_DISCOVER arguments.  */
linux/in.h:67:#define IP_MTU_DISCOVER 10
linux/in.h:71:#define IP_MTU  14
linux/in.h:80:/* IP_MTU_DISCOVER values */`

Comment: Strange enough `bits/in.h`  seems to define the MTU value for the IPv6 instead: `#define IPV6_MTU 24`

Comment: That is quite strange ... What are the entries between lines 61 & 67 in `bits.h` ? Comment seems to indicate those are parameter for `IP_MTU_DISCOVER `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: I don't think there is an answer. I'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 8) and I have the exact same problem:

- man 7 ip says I can query the MTU
- grep -Re IP_MTU /usr/include/* indicates the macro exists only in linux/in.h
- I can't use linux/in.h or I get a ton of errors

So, I guess the only thing to be done is workaround by setting the MTU discover, constantly tweaking the MTU and watching for the kernel to shut you down when you try to send something too big. That's what I'm going to do.